# Permission Issues

Tags: php, permissions

Having an issue with unlink() even when executing a script as **root**.

Getting this error:

```
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/services/training/add.php): Permission denied in /var/www/html/sites/services/functions.php on line 228
```

The owner of the file is **root** and the file permissions are **775** so it should work.

Are there any further steps I can take to troubleshoot this? Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal .. I guess you are an ubuntu user

so just do this

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/services/
```

By Default your access is limited . So you have to extend your access using this chmod command :) .. that's it :)

Comment: It's on a CentOS server. Surely I would't need to open it up to 777 though? That seems like a poor solution, since I'd need to do this for a full directory of PHP scripts and I need them as secure as possible.

Comment: sorry! I thought you are hosting this script on Local server :)

Comment: Ah, no - this is a live web server.